# Revert to previous local version on github

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have done some changes on a branch but i did not commit.

Then i did a merge and now my changes are lost, is there any way i can recover it?

Newbie github user here

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you (1) didn't commit changes to your local branch ("git add", "git commit") or (2) didn't push commits from your local branch to remote ("git push")?

In first case - probably there is nothing you can do (since git never tracked your changes).

In second - You can use interactive rebase (see docs on "git rebase -i") to rewrite history of your local branch (you'd probably want to get rid of "merging commit" on top of your local branch. In any case be careful with any history rewrite, all gotchas related to amending commits, for example, applies here).

Comment: oh, yes just remembered - You can also do "git reset --hard HEAD^" in second case too (this will drop top commit from branch you are staying in).